# How to apply colors that are stored in mongodb to ejs templates?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am storing colors codes as a input from user into mongodb through mongoose. I tried to apply those codes into ejs template parts for styling. Can't figure it how can i do  that.

I tried this way but it is showing error mark here :

Please my image : [image]

colors are applying but the problems is  error mark. I should remove that error mark.How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't send code as screenshot. It appears that you're being warned by the VSCode that you have syntax error but it appears ok, unless you have misspelled the variable name `Primarycolor`

```html
<button style="background-color: <%= Primarycolor %>!important">Send a free request</button>
```

Have you tried to render that page?

Comment: I tried to render the page but not able to remove that error

Comment: What does the VSCode says when you hover over the error? And does it render if you manually enter the color?

Comment: It is rendering color in both ways , but it is simply showing red error mark both to file and place where i am rendering dynamic color. That might some what problem to client

Comment: Might be that you have some alterations on that file, try to copy entire code to another file and see if it will show the markings again. Can you share that file?